# Como hacer que un select sea validado solo cuando el usuario de click en un radio button con valor= 1 con el plugin de formvalidation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tengo un problema cuando utilizo el plugin de formvalidation, debido a que no importa si doy click en el radio con value=0 o value=1, me sigue pidiendo que llene el campo select, pero solo quiero que lo haga cuando value=1.

**HTML**

```
<form action="" id="Vacante"> <h3 class="page-header">Tipo de vacante</h3>                 <div class="row">
       <div class="col-sm-12">
           <label>Tipo de Vacante</label>
               <br /> 
                 <input type="radio" name="Vacantes_Tipo" id="Vacantes_TipoNo" value="0" checked="checked"> Nueva Vacante <input type="radio" name="Vacantes_Tipo" id="Vacantes_TipoSi" value="1"> Vacante por rotación de personal                                       
<hr />                                                         
<div class="form-group" id="VacanteBaja">                     
<label>Razón de Baja</label>                     
<select class="form-control" name="ddl_Vacantes_Baja" id="ddl_Vacantes_Baja" data-live-search="true">
      <option value="" selected>Selecciona..</option>        
<option value="1">Enfermedad</option>  </select>                               </div>
         </form>
```

**Jquery con FormValidation**

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#Vacante')
                 .formValidation({
                     excluded: ':disabled',
                     framework: 'bootstrap',
                     icon: {
                         valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                         invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                         validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
                     },
                     fields: {
                        Vacantes_Tipo: {
                             validators: {
                                 notEmpty: {
                                     message: 'This field is required'
                                 }
                             }
                         },
                         ddl_Vacantes_Baja: {
                             validators: {
                                 notEmpty: {
                                     message: 'This field is required'
                                 }
                             }
                         },
                                                                  qty: {
                             validators: {
                                 notEmpty: {
                                     message: 'This field is required'
                                 }
                             }
                         }        
                     }
                })
    });
```

[Aqui esta el codigo en codepen](http://codepen.io/guille1194/pen/GjRYNv)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según la documentación, puedes hacer un callback para este tipo de validación condicional, la cual es realizada cada vez que cambia el valor del campo de los radios:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#Vacante')
             .formValidation({
                 excluded: ':disabled',
                 framework: 'bootstrap',
                 icon: {
                     valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                     invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                     validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
                 },
                 fields: {
                    Vacantes_Tipo: {
                         validators: {
                             notEmpty: {
                                 message: 'This field is required'
                             }
                         }
                     },
            ddl_Vacantes_Baja: {
                validators: {
                    callback: {
                        message: 'This field is required',
                        callback: function(value, validator, $field) {
                            var vacantesBaja = $('#Vacante').find('[name="Vacantes_Tipo"]:checked').val();
                            return (vacantesBaja != 1) ? true : (value != '');
                        }
                    }
                }
            } 
                 }
            })
    .on('change', '[name="Vacantes_Tipo"]', function(e) {
        $('#Vacante').formValidation('revalidateField', 'ddl_Vacantes_Baja');
    })
});
```

Puedes ver más información aquí: http://formvalidation.io/examples/conditional-validation/

Comment: ok, esto esta mas cerca de mi respuesta, solo que ocupo que cuando el radio button sea igual a 0, no active el formvalidation, y cuando sea igual a uno si, porque de momento esto es lo que hace. http://codepen.io/guille1194/pen/GjRYNv

Comment: No entiendo entonces que es lo que quieres que haga el código, leí tu pregunta varias veces y asumí que mi respuesta es el resultado esperado. Puedes darme más detalles? No me queda tan claro entonces.

Comment: bueno, creo que no me explique bien, cuando el radio button este en la posicion de nueva vacante, no se debe de activar nada del formvalidation, pero cuando esta en el radio button de vacante por otros motivos, debe de activar el formvalidation para el select razon de baja, y el primer valor del select que es selecciona, debe de marcarse como incorrecto. aqui dejo el codigo. http://codepen.io/guille1194/pen/GjRYNv

Comment: O sea que si el radio está en la posición de "nueva vacante", ninguno de los campos debe ser validado?

Comment: si, es correcto :)

Comment: Olvida lo que dije, tu logica esta bien, solo faltaba un pequenio detalle, que el select del primer campo no lo validara, aqui esta el codigo http://codepen.io/guille1194/pen/GjRYNv?editors=1010. Gracias :D

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurre que podrías hacer lo siguiente con la función [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) de jQuery. Siempre usa el método prop para habilitar o deshabilitar elementos cuando estes usando jQuery.

```
var vacantes = $('#Vacantes_TipoNo');
if (vacantes == 0){
  $('#ddl_Vacantes_Baja').prop("disabled", false); //El elemento estará ahora activado
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var vacantes = $('#Vacantes_TipoNo');
  
  $('input').click(function(){
    if(vacantes.val() == 0){
     $('#ddl_Vacantes_Baja').prop("disabled", true);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" id="Vacante"> <h3 class="page-header">Tipo de vacante</h3>                 <div class="row">
       <div class="col-sm-12">
           <label>Tipo de Vacante</label>
               <br /> 
                 <input type="radio" name="Vacantes_Tipo" id="Vacantes_TipoNo" value="0" > Nueva Vacante <input type="radio" name="Vacantes_Tipo" id="Vacantes_TipoSi" value="1" checked="checked"> Vacante por rotación de personal                                       
<hr />                                                         
<div class="form-group" id="VacanteBaja">                     
<label>Razón de Baja</label>                     
<select class="form-control" name="ddl_Vacantes_Baja" id="ddl_Vacantes_Baja" data-live-search="true">
      <option value="" selected>Selecciona..</option>        
<option value="1">Enfermedad</option>  </select>                               </div>
         </form>
```

Comment: ok, no entiendo bien la primera parte de codigo,  debido a que me interesa  que cuando value sea =1 se active, pero aqui solo doy click a otro radio button y siempre esta disable